# How to solve " NameError: name 'model' is not defined " error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

While trying to predict the output I am facing the error `NameError: name 'model' is not defined`. How to solve this.

```
%%time
# Lstm
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(data_dim, input_shape=(95,data_dim), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(data_dim))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=96)
model.summary()
```

The above model trained well. While trying `model.predict(X_test1)`, I am having the issue mentioned above.

Comment: Remove the `%%time` and run the cell again. You will have variable `model` now in the global context. Since Jupyter 5, time magic functions are executed out of main context.

Comment: Thanks Richard. that works. Can you write the answer below?

Comment: @RichardNemeth as OP suggest, kindly post this as an answer, so it can be accepted and be here for future reference (comments can easily get deleted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the magic function `%%time`. In the latest version of IPython in Jupyter, running a cell with `time` magic function as a header runs the cell out of the global context. This is also true for `%%timeit`.

Practically it means that all the new variables defined in the `%%time` cell do not exist in the main context, including your `model` variable, which is why you receive the NameError exception, since the interpreter can not find a variable named `model`.

Removing the `%%time` line from your cell will do the trick.